# Aren't there any thought criminals who commit suicide in Oceania and what would it mean for the government?

Tags: george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four

The Inner Party doesn't want Winston and Julia dead as long as they are opposing Big Brother and the government. Oceania's government wants everyone to "love" Big Brother and Ingsoc, and willing to execute thought criminals only if they cease to be thought criminals. Hence, would Ingsoc consider it a failure if a thought criminal commited suicide before they could be caught? How would the Party react if they didn't get the thought criminal? E.g. if Winston and Julia had commited dual suicide, would the Party have "failed" and what would they do? Do such suicides happen in Oceania?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered in the book. The Party has acted to make  suicide difficult, and Winston lacks the courage to go through with it. Even so, Winston thinks there are some people who do it anyway.

From the very end of Part One

> It was at night that they came for you, always at night. The proper  thing  was  to  kill  yourself  before  they  got  you.  Un-doubtedly some people did so. Many of the disappearances were  actually  suicides.  But  it  needed  desperate  courage  to  kill  yourself  in  a  world  where  firearms,  or  any  quick  and certain poison, were completely unprocurable. He thought with  a  kind  of  astonishment  of  the  biological  uselessness of  pain  and  fear,  the  treachery  of  the  human  body  which always  freezes  into  inertia  at  exactly  the  moment  when  a special  effort  is  needed.

Later, O'Brien makes a promise:

> When  finally  you  are  caught,  you  will  get  no  help.  We  never  help our members. At most, when it is absolutely necessary that someone  should  be  silenced,  we  are  occasionally  able  to smuggle  a  razor  blade  into  a  prisoner’s  cell.

And from later after Winston has been arrested

> He thought oftener of O’Brien, with  a  flickering  hope.  O’Brien  might  know  that  he  had been arrested. The Brotherhood, he had said, never tried to save its members. But there was the razor blade; they would send the razor blade if they could. There would be perhaps five seconds before the guard could rush into the cell. The blade would bite into him with a sort of burning coldness, and  even  the  fingers  that  held  it  would  be  cut  to  the  bone. Everything came back to his sick body, which shrank trembling  from  the  smallest  pain.  He  was  not  certain  that  he would use the razor blade even if he got the chance. It was more natural to exist from moment to moment, accepting another ten minutes’ life even with the certainty that there was torture at the end of it.